# How to convert a string 1087000 as $1,087K in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsnumberformatter

I have a set of values returned from the web service as strings in formats such as XXXXX or XXXXXX or XXXXXX..., the number of digits may differ.

I want to convert them from the above mentioned formats to something with $x,xxxK.

How to do that?

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Do you care about localisation or is this for an app that will only work in the USA ?

Answer (score 0):

use `[str doubleValue];`

then divide by 1000 to or more to set your desired format